# Get first and last 100 characters of a text file

Tags: php, performance, readfile

I have a text file and within that text file, there are just few lines but contains about 5-10 million characters. I'm using `file_get_contents` but because it reads the whole file so the performance become very slow and hangs sometimes when executing. Is there a more efficient way to get first and last 100 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this to get first 100 characters:

```
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
$data = fread($fp, 100);
echo $data;
fclose($fp);
```

and get last 100 characters:

```
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
fseek($fp, -100, SEEK_END);
$data = fread($fp, 100);
echo $data;
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`fread`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to specify the number of bytes that have to be read from the file.

For example:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$contents = fread($handle, 100);
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
```

However, there is no way to be sure that this will be a string of 100 characters. This depends on the character encoding.